# A dynamic table plugin to get user input

Tags: plugins, table

I just wonder if there is a Wordpress table plugin where the user can add some data in some certain cell and get a result in another. Just look at the following image:

[image]

In a table like above, I want the user to fill in the `NO #` column and based on that get a calculated amount in the `result` column. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can't really ask for plugin recommendations here - for whatever reason.. so I can't recommend you look at "tablepress" ;)

Comment: @QStudio. If you were not to come up with any recommendations, you'd better not drop any lines at all. Anyhow, thanks for the reply. 'Tablepress' is not able to do what I aim to do.

Comment: Tablepress can do it, via add-ons, but you may as well just ask for a javascript solution to this problem, it is not so complex and you question will not be deleted.